# Overall performance of PC slowing down. Can someone help me with this issue?

Tags: memory, cpu, performance, hardware-failure, gpu

I’ve currently had my computer for about a year and a half, and for one of my first builds, it has worked very well to this point. Recently, the performance for my PC has drastically gone down. I’ve always been a programmer and a gamer as well, and as I attempt to play games that I usually get 60-120 FPS on, I barely reach 5 FPS! I can barely run games like Fortnite at the lowest settings anymore, which is ridiculous because I’ve had them at the highest settings with 60 stable FPS prior to this issue. Not only with games as well, Windows overall has been very slow, I can barely right click anything without having it have massive points of lag. I’ve usually been having an occurring issue when it comes to 3D Rendering on my GPU, but I’m still not sure if that’s the issue. I’ve done almost every single step that I’ve thought of. I’ve ran memtest86, 0 errors. Scanned for malware, and my AV did find malware and removed them, but it turns out the programs weren’t even malware, so I don’t believe that was the issue. I overclocked my CPU, performance did not go up whatsoever. Checked the temperatures of my computer, they’re normal, 45-50 on my CPU, and my GPU reaches 80 at max. I even remounted my GPU and inspected parts of my PC and everything seems normal to me. My hard drive has 1TB of space and I have 112 GB free, to me that should be enough without any problem. I’m very lost at this point and I hope someone can help me.
Here are my specs if necessary:
- NDIVIA 1050 Ti
- AMD Ryzen CPU
- MSI b350 motherboard
- 1TB of Hard drive 
- 8 GB of RAM 
P.S: Not sure if it could be my power supply? Haven’t thought about that entirely.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Based on the 18mo age, I suspect a failing Seagate hard drive.

Comment: How would you confirm that though?

Comment: Any tool that supports reading SMART data will show you the `Raw_Read_Error_Rate` and `Seek_Error_Rate` are spiking through the roof. If you use one that monitors them in or close to real time you'll see hundreds or possibly thousands per minute. There are [many available](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_S.M.A.R.T._tools), but I like SmartMonTools for CLI or Defraggler for GUI.

Comment: So should I test these or do I just replace it?

Comment: The tests are pretty quick, but based on your description I'd replace it. Get an SSD.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the long awaited response! After a week of observing the issue, I finally realized that only 1 piece of RAM was being detected. I had 4096 RAM installed when I had overall 8GB of RAM, and I took one piece of RAM out and turns out it was placed incorrectly for some odd reason? I just put it back in place and it worked perfectly with perfect performance now!

Thanks for anyone who tried to help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  The recommendations for replacing your hard drive were bad, unwarranted advice.  Your answer may save other readers from needlessly replacing their hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @shawn. According to your usage (especially gaming part) this is very normal. You should replace your main hard drive to an ssd (preferably -if your motherboard supports- a NVMe one). After migration you can consider buying another backup drive while your old and tired drive works. I'd be quick if I were you.